# Report watermark disappears when reportviewer used

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports in VS 2010. I have a report with a watermark added. When I use 'main report preview' the watermark shows up just fine. When I use code to show the report it is gone.

```
    InitializeComponent()

    ReportViewer.Owner = Me
    Dim durocReport As New Duroc

    durocReport.SetParameterValue("registration", reg)
    durocReport.SetDatabaseLogon("", "")

    ReportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = durocReport
```

The report shows perfectly except the watermark/background is missing, all of the data is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by cutting the resolution of the image from 300 to 85. It seems to be a file size issue. The image was also missing anytime I reloaded visual studio. It currently works, I will just have to mess around with the image quality until it looks good enough to use.